# Files and folders became read only, cannot back up data

Tags: read-only

I need one urgent help.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. My hard drive is only one year old.

Suddenly all of my folders and files became read only. After checking in Google, I came to know that this is something related to corrupt file system. I cannot transfer the files and folders to another machine or to an external hard drive. I need to back up my files immediately because otherwise I will loose many of my work.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Following this thread, I have performed

```
dmesg | less
```

[Why has my file-system turned read-only after updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105793/why-has-my-file-system-turned-read-only-after-updates)

Now I am not sure what particular error to look for, but I can see following

```
[    1.844462] drm: registered panic notifier
[    1.844474] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    3.082945] EXT4-fs (sda1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    3.082951] EXT4-fs (sda1): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    6.511793] EXT4-fs (sda1): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[    6.511810] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 9962260
[    6.511925] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 9966039
[    6.511972] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 9966038
[    6.511991] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 9966043




[    6.553657] EXT4-fs (sda1): 10 orphan inodes deleted
[    6.553663] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete



[   17.401897] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,user_xattr
[   18.142384] init: failsafe main process (789) killed by TERM signal
```

EDIT2:

Following is the output when I ran fsck from recovery mode:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
dev/sda1: 848236/30400512 files (0.5% non contiguous), 35852000/121574400 blocks
Finished, please  press Enter
```

SOLVED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the exact same problem, but in windows, all what i have done is disk check and it did the trick, you can always do disk check in ubuntu by entering the recovery mode and choosing disk check, if this dosn't work, i suggest you to backup your drive cause it might be a faulty or file system is corrupted, in this case i suggest you to backup your data and run ubuntu from live cd and use `gparted` to re partition your disk

Comment: Why would OP need to repartition his disk? That's irrelevant here IMO. Also you're not telling how to back up the data, which is the question about.

Comment: i said a check disk might fix it but if its a disk or MBR faulty, i think he should re partition the disk, i didn't told him he should do that now.

Comment: I cannot even enter into recovery mode as pressing the shift key during booting does not show the grub menu. The following is there in /etc/default/grub file GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=15

Comment: good edit, as i see that the file system is corrupted, as i told you it happened like mine, i played around with /etc/fstab and i found : error=remount-ro which means if any errors remount with read-only
and as i see that it will enable write permission in recovery mode, im not sure why you cant get into it, try repairing using windows (if present)

Comment: and hey, the error happened to me because a disk error, i was shrinking a partition and after reboot the MBR is corrupted, i repaired MBR but this problem happened to me
anyway, have you done something special before you got this error?

Comment: By pressing the right side shift key, I could enter into recovery mode. Then I ran the fsck from recovery mode. But files and folders are still read only.

Comment: @Yousef's No I did not do anything special. My laptop was running slow and it became read only automatically.