# xubuntu changes file permissions automatically and unable to change file permissions via terminal

Tags: root

when the computer is booting up, it gives this massage
[image]

i pressed F to repair. after 10 sec i could log in normally.

but had some issues with file permissions in home partition and tried to change them. them could not be changed. so i restarted the computer. after the restating i could not even log in as root.

[image]

i have an external hard drive in EXT4 file format. Ubuntu change it's file permissions also after plug it...

(sorry for bad English :/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like your main filesystem has some errors, mounting as read-only (the `Read-only file system` message) and the checks at bootup aren't fixing them. Did you try pressing <kbd>f</kbd> to attempt to fix it when it said to?  If it doesn't fix it automatically you may need to log into a recovery mode or with a live cd/usb/dvd and then `fsck` your partitions

See `man fsck.ext4` , you'll probably want to use `fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda1` or whatever your partitions are called. Use `lsblk` or `sudo blkid` to see what's what. If they're not all ext, then plain `fsck` should figure out the type on it's own.

It looks like at least the home or `/` has errors. Try looking at what's mounted with `ro` (has `ro` in the ()'d options at end of each line) from the `mount` command. You can only safely `fsck` an ext-type partition when it's not mounted, so may need to boot live to do that. If the external hard drive has errors too it should be `fsck`'d also.

And to help avoid filesystem errors in the future, unmount partitions (hard disks, usb's, everything) before you turn them off or remove them. Just unplugging them (or unplugging the computer) could corrupt filesystems.

Comment: I ran fsck.ext4 -c to check the partitions and fsck.ext4 -f to repair.. i think it  worked.. thank you sir

Comment: actually it didn't work :/

Comment: It could be a tricky problem, maybe fsck did fix it once but the problem occurred again. What's mounted as `ro` when this happens? And does `sudo` work for anything else, even `ls`? This Q has some tips that may help, http://askubuntu.com/questions/105793/why-has-my-file-system-turned-read-only-after-updates like check `dmesg` (or `/var/log/syslog`) for any HD related messages. You're running from an external HD? I used to have FS problems with USB drives, they'd get corrupted for apparently no reason, switching to ext3 (with it's journal) helped but ext4 should be the same or even better...